# Tzidkat HaTzadik - HaRav Tzadok HaKohen MiLublin

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism

Can someone recommend an edition of Tzidkat HaTzadik by HaRav Tzadok HaKohen MiLublin? I am looking for an edition with clear type, accurate text, and perhaps some explanatory notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good anthology of all of his works with very clear type which you can purchase [here](https://seforimcenter.com/Sifrei-Rabbi-Tzadok-HaKohen-of-Lublin-5-vol.__p-10458.aspx).

As far as individual versions with explanatory notes I would recommend two:

1. The two-volume edition, available with "*Biur Meshulav*", accompanying explanatory notes [here](https://seforimplace.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=7559). You can see from the sample page below that it has "Biurei HaChassidus" - i.e. explanation on the chassidish concepts and 'mekoros v'tziyunim' which outline the sources behind the ideas mentioned.

[image]

2. There is also another two-volume version containing explanatory comments called *Neimos HaTzedek* [here](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/cdqt-hcdiq-r-cdvq-hkhn-e-b-neimvt-hcdq-b-krkim.html). The blurb there writes as follows:

> מאת הגה"ק שר התורה רבינו צדוק הכהן זצוק"ל מלובלין ונוסף עליו ביאור נרחב משולב עם דברי קדשו בתוספות מקורות ומובאות משאר ספרי המחבר הנקרא בשם 'נעימת צדק' ולתועלת המעמיקים נוספו הערות בשולי הגליון, ובסופו השלמות ומילואים להרחיב את שיטת רבינו בנושאים שונים
>
> From HaGaon HaKodosh, Sar HaTorah our Rebbe Rav Tzadok HaKohein ztvk"l from Lublin. In addition, there is an extensive commentary combined with his holy words in source additions and quotations from the rest of the author's books called 'Neimas HaTzedek'. And for more in-depth purposes, comments were added at the margins of the issue, and at the end, summaries to expand the method of our Rabbi on various issues.

In the meantime are you aware that you can access it on sefaria [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Tzidkat_HaTzadik)

Comment: Wow, thank you for these wonderful recommendations. Of the two, the Oz VeHadar edition seems like the better choice. The printing is crystal clear and the commentary is lucid and concise. If you had to choose, which edition would you buy?

Comment: It is purely down to personal taste. They are both great editions!

Comment: If you feel this answer sufficiently answers your question, pls feel free to click the checkmark